# Android studio's Android SDK download button is not activated

Tags: android, sdk

I'm having trouble with my android studio and I even changed my windows, now I'm just frustrated. Can someone help me? I almost looked everywhere.

[So this is when I've installed android studio and this appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYrN.png)

[Then it automatically goes to this page and wants to download android SDK but the check box is not activated! and as you can see the download size is 0!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9dT8.png)

[And that's the next one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnVB9.png)

So I quitted the setup and opened the SDK manager from the android studio and this is what it says:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJPdq.png)

does anyone know what should I do to download SDK? And by the way, I'm living in Iran, that's one of those countries that include United States sanctions. Do you think it's related and if Yes what should I do?

p.s: This is the first time I'm asking a question on Stackoverflow, so forgive me if I did something wrong in the asking process.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some changes to my IP I could fix the problem. So, if anyone has the same problem I think it's related to their countries limit problems. You should change your IP.